# Logged user on Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Is there a way to query a distant host as to whether someone is currently logged in through Remote Desktop? Or that there is a currently active connection?

Asking because bumping users on a workstation has become an issue, and I'd like to check without bothering them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the query command if you are within the local network. For example:

```
Query session /server:*yourservernameorIP*
```

you can use both friendly names and IPs in the "/server:" section.

For more info on Query commands see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186592).

Comment: Awesome. At least it would be if I didn't get an "Error 1722 getting sessionnames" and "Error [1722]:The RPC server is unavailable". While I am connected from the same machine! Almost tempted to start a new question on that.

Comment: Bad phrasing. Your answer is awesome, my situation is not.

Comment: When connecting to a workstation, you may need to [allow remote RPC access](http://www.codesoil.net/2007/08/16/big-problem-access-denied-when-using-qwinstaexe-or-wtsopenserver-api/).

Comment: Also, once you get `query` working, you should take a look at "Terminal Server Administration Tool" (downloadable as part of Windows 2003 Admin Tools).